# HTML search input, and HTML textarea width shrinks on iPad

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 and AngularJs for this one. 
I am doing this for the input `type='search'`:

```
<input type="search" class="form-control" id='roomSearch' placeholder="Search" ng-model='qText'>
```

And this for the textarea:

```
<textarea name='question' id='question' rows='8' ng-model='q.text' class='form-control' ng-maxlength='{{$root.globals.maxLen.med}}' required></textarea>
```

It looks fine in all major browsers on iPhone and desktop, however; the iPad is rendering these fields like this:

[image: input search]

And here

[image]

UPDATE!
Here is the CSS for the search box

```
     #roomSearch {
       margin-top: 8px;
       float: right;
     }
```

Here is the css for the text area

```
       .question-form textarea {
       width: 100%;
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not see an answer, and this is old so I am guessing the author figured it out, but this worked for me:

```
textarea, input {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

This made the textarea and the input fill the full width of the browser.